# PHP Nested foreach loop, how to affect (parent?)

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a nested foreach loop running through categories in a database. When the user is viewing a category the category ID is set and that menu item gets it's class set as "active".

The issue I'm having is when a user is viewing a subcategory, I still need it's PARENT to be set to active.

```
// Run through category ID's and output info
            foreach ($GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->tree->nodesByPid[$catid] as $rowid) {
                $row = $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->catsById[$rowid];

                //Check to see if user has access
                if (($accessible_cats !== false) && (!in_array($row['categoryid'],$accessible_cats)) && ($row['security'] == "private")) {
                    continue;
                }

                // If we're viewing a category, output "active" as a class in the menu
                if (isset($GLOBALS['CategoryId'])
                    && ($GLOBALS['CategoryId']) == $row['categoryid'])  {
                    $activeCat = "active";
                } else {
                    $activeCat = "";
                }

                //Pass through global variables
                $GLOBALS['Link'] = GetUrl('category', $row['categoryid']);
                $GLOBALS['Text'] = $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_TEMPLATE']->DisablePlaceholders(strip_tags($row['name']));
                $GLOBALS['Active'] = $activeCat;
                $output .= $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_TEMPLATE']->GetSnippet('CategoryRowCell');

                //If subcategories exist
                    if (isset($GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->tree->nodesByPid[$rowid])
                        && is_array($GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->tree->nodesByPid[$rowid])
                        && !empty($GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->tree->nodesByPid[$rowid])) {

                        $output .= $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_TEMPLATE']->GetSnippet('CategoryGridHeaderSub');

                            //For every subcategory, output data
                            foreach ($GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->tree->nodesByPid[$rowid] as $subrowid) {
                                $subrow = $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->catsById[$subrowid];

                                //Here's the part I can't get working. Need to output "active" to the PARENT id($row I believe)
                                if (isset($GLOBALS['CategoryId'])
                                    && ($GLOBALS['CategoryId']) == $subrow['categoryid'])  {
                                    $activeCat = "active";
                                } else {
                                    $activeCat = "";
                                }

                                //Set Global Variables
                                $GLOBALS['Link'] = GetUrl('category', $subrow['categoryid']);
                                $GLOBALS['Text'] = $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_TEMPLATE']->DisablePlaceholders(strip_tags($subrow['name']));
                                $GLOBALS['Active'] = $activeCat;

                                $output .= $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_TEMPLATE']->GetSnippet('CategoryRowCellSub');
                            }
                        }
                        $output .= $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_TEMPLATE']->GetSnippet('CategoryGridFooterSub');
            }
```

So the part I need to figure out is in the nested foreach loop, how can I affect the parent ID or something of the like.

Current Output when viewing parents(Working perfectly)

```
<li class="categoryItem active"><a href="#">Parent 1</a>
<ul class="categorySubList">
<li class="categorySubItem"><a class="categorylink" href="/categories/Parent+1/Subcategory+1/">Subcategory 1</a></li>
<li class="categorySubItem "><a class="categorylink" href="/categories/Parent+1/Subcategory+2/">Subcategory 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Current Output when viewing children(not working)

```
<li class="categoryItem"><a href="#">Parent 1</a><!--this list item needs to be active-->
<ul class="categorySubList">
<li class="categorySubItem active"><a class="categorylink" href="/categories/Parent+1/Subcategory+1/">Subcategory 1</a></li>
<li class="categorySubItem "><a class="categorylink" href="/categories/Parent+1/Subcategory+2/">Subcategory 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What problems you're having so far? What have you tried? How did it go?

Comment: @PatrickBassut Parent level categories works perfectly. The issue comes when I get to subcategories(nested ul's).

'<li class="categoryItem"><a href="#">Parent 1</a>
<ul class="categorySubList">
<li class="categorySubItem active"><a class="categorylink" href="/categories/Parent+1/Subcategory+1/">Subcategory 1</a></li>
<li class="categorySubItem "><a class="categorylink" href="/categories/Parent+1/Subcategory+2/">Subcategory 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>'

Comment: This is some coding style I would never accept...

Comment: @RoyalBg can you elaborate? Do you mean the way I am writing the PHP? This is the first time I have ever worked with it so any tips are welcome.

Comment: @TheEks too many globals, most of them are holding objects

Comment: @TheEks some don't encourage the use of $_GLOBALS at all.

Comment: @PatrickBassut What is a better way to work with it? 

I'm working within a system(Interspire Knowledge Manager) that already does this and just need to modify the system some. I don't want to go overboard and re-write the software...

Comment: @TheEks Well, from a beautiful code view perspective you should rewrite the code. But since you're trying to make minor changes, it's better to stick with the $_GLOBALS. The active attribute remains empty, then ? Try to output the value of $GLOBALS['CategoryId'] and $subrow['categoryid'] so we can have a little bit more of info about the problem.

Comment: @PatrickBassut Noted. Seeming as this software was last updated in ~2009 I think I'll just use that as an excuse :)

Any thoughts for how to access the parent and create a GLOBAL for it to be active?

Comment: @TheEks This software is using a library that manipulates a DOM. So, about how to deal with that library, I really can't help you. Since you didn't even mentioned the name. I'm wondering you don't know.

Comment: @PatrickBassut When using a PHP foreach loop nested inside another, is there a way to reference back to the item in the original loop?

Comment: @TheErks What you mean by "Reference back to the item?"

Comment: @PatrickBassut So let's say the first loop is on ID 3, it's now finding the subcategories in the nested foreach loop. While it's running the nested foreach can I tell it to do something with the parent(ID 3)? Sorry for my potential lack of clarity, I just started with this all on Tuesday.